# Medical/Physics Question - Cut Off Finger Preservation

Tags: thermodynamics, biophysics, biology, medical-physics

This question might require some knowledge of medical/tissue, but physicists seem to know everything, so figured I've give it a shot here ;)

When people put cut off fingers they are told to put the fingers on ice.

I assume the cold temperature does something to help preserve the finger. If so, my question would be, wouldn't it make more sense to put the cut off finger in a bucket of ice then put water in it, so that the temperature transfer happens faster?

If the water runs a risk diluting the blood or anything, then perhaps putting the finger in a zip lock bag then doing the same process with the zip lock bag.

So to recap:

1. Does my solution transfer the heat faster.
2. Is there any benefit to either approach mentioned?

Comment: Water + Ice probably does cool the finger faster.  There are probably other issues like over hydrating the cells and causing them to burst that make your recommendation a poor one.

Comment: You've got ten fingers - surely you can make do with eight and forgo two in the name of science to do the experiment!

Comment: Oh s**t, I've just cut of a finger; "no honey, let's not go to the hospital just yet: just let me ask the best way to preserve it on Physics Stack Exchange and then we'll go!".